# Looking for a weird function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am looking for a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$ that satisfies these 3 conditions:

1. There exist $c>0,k>0$ such that for all $n$, $f(n) \leq c \cdot n^k$
2. Let $b\in \mathbb{N^{\geq 2}}$. For any $d>0$, there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$, we have $f(bn)\geq df(n)$

**Edit**: The original 2nd condition: Let $b\in \mathbb{N^{\geq 2}}$. For any $d>0$, there exists $n_0$ such that we have $f(bn_0)\geq df(n_0)$, ie $\frac{f(bn)}{f(n)}$ is unbounded.

3. $\exists n_0$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0$ we have $f(n+1) \geq f(n)$

Any hints on the general form of such a function?

**Edit:** Any polynomial function wouldn't satisfy the 2nd condition. Any exponential/factorial function wouldn't satisfy the 1st condition. I have tried using online calculators to evaluate the limit of $\frac{\log((bn)!)}{\log(n)!}$, it isn't unbounded. I can't really think of any other types of functions.

Comment: Welcome to mse! What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: In 1., you mean there exist $c,k>0$ such that $f(n)\le cn^k $ for all $n$?

Comment: $(bn)!/n!$ is unbounded but $n!$ grows faster than any polynomial (or even exponential).

Comment: For 2, it seems you mean that the ratio is unbounded as a function of $n$ for fixed $b$.  Is that true?  It would be simpler to just set $b=2$ as that will be the controlling case.  I think you can use 2 to show it grows faster than any polynomial and in 1 you are comparing it to a polynomial so there is no such function.

Comment: Just to be clear, you changed (2) from saying $f(bn)/f(n)$ must unbounded to saying it must diverge to infinity? The latter is a stricter condition, and I'm pretty sure makes it impossible.

Comment: @elemelons why is "diverge to infinity" stricter than unbounded?

Comment: The sequence $1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,\cdots$ for example is unbounded but doesn't diverge to infinity.

Comment: @elemelons ok thank you! I added both versions in my question, can you confirm if my definition of "unboundness" is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constant $c$ is superfluous so I will omit it.

**First Version**. Condition (2) originally said $f(bn)/f(n)$ was unbounded for any $b\ge2$.

Define $f(n)=2^{\large 2^{\Large \lfloor\lg\lfloor\lg n\rfloor \rfloor}}$. Obviously $f$ is nondecreasing, and $f(n)\le n$ for all $n$. Defining the quotient $q(n)=f(2n)/f(n)$, we have $f(bn)/f(n)\ge f(2n)/f(n)=q(n)$, and $q(2^{\large 2^{\Large t}-1})=2^{\large 2^{\Large t-1}}$ is a subsequence which diverges to $\infty$, hence the ratios are unbounded.

**Second Version**. Condition (2) was revised to say $f(bn)/f(n)\to\infty$ for any $b$.

This is impossible. Suppose we had such an $f$. Define $g(t)=\lg f(2^t)$. The conditions imply $g$ is bounded by $kt$ for some $k$, the differences $g(t+1)-g(t)$ diverge to $\infty$, and $g$ is nondecreasing.

Fix the constant $k$. At some point, $g(t+1)-g(t)>k$ for all $t\ge t_0$. But then $g(t)$ is growing faster than $kt$ and must eventually overtake it. Explicitly, $g(t)$ is bounded below by

$$ g(t)=g(t_0)+\sum_{s=t_0}^{t-1} [g(s+1)-g(s)] $$
$$ \ge g(t_0)+(t-t_0)[g(t_0+1)-g(t_0)] $$

which is a linear function of $t$ with slope $>k$, hence must overtake $kt$, a contradiction.